# Generating Youtube Share Link

Tags: c#, youtube, youtube-api

Hi guys I need to get Youtube share link from the embed code. At the moment I am simply using

```
var sharelink = "http://youtu.be/" + videoId;
```

I just wanted to make sure if it is really this simple or am I making a mistake using this 
approach.

Comment: Does it work when you browse to that link? If it does: yes, this seems pretty simple.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Are there any other rules to sharelinks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a perfectly valid way to generate a share link from the embed code. Also node that if you append a URL fragment to the videoID:

```
https://youtu.be/f3_JLyVgbEA#t=105
```

Then the shared link will start that many seconds into the video.

Also note that, while http:// will work, https:// is also an option for you.